# sublime text 2 remove diacritics

Tags: sublimetext2, diacritics

I use to code Sublime Text 2 and sometimes I need remove diacritics.
How to remove diacritics from part of text? Is there som filter or something?

Thanks for any suggestions.
Feri

Comment: outside of Sublime Text, you could use something from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string).

Comment: @hayden thanks for suggestion. I made a small plugin https://github.com/frkosk/AccentsRemover

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to look at this question and it's answers:

[Regex - What would be regex for matching foreign characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009993/regex-what-would-be-regex-for-matching-foreign-characters)

You can use the regex find utility of Sublime and try the regex that is suggested by [Fredrik Mörk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93623/fredrik-mork)

```
\p{L}
```