# Jquery regex doesn't work with swedish åäöÅÄÖ

Tags: php, jquery

```
var word=/@(\w+)/ig; //@abc Match
```

How do I get this code to work with ÅÄÖ

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex - What would be regex for matching foreign characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009993/regex-what-would-be-regex-for-matching-foreign-characters)

Comment: Try to use this regex: `/@([\u00C0-\u00ff]+)/g`. This will match tons of other useless cr*p (`çÇáÀãï` and others) but works as intended. If you check for that codepoint interval, you can tune it to your specific task.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `\p{L}` in regex if you wanted to match are letters

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009993/regex-what-would-be-regex-for-matching-foreign-characters) for a detailed info

Comment: i havnt tried this..actually..am not that good in regex too..when i  searched i got this thats why i mentioned as an answer here ..lets check if it was helpful for op..

Comment: Try this in your console: `/@(\p{L}+)/.test('@\p{L}')`  (should return `true`). If it returns `true`, it's not helpful.

Comment: Hi I am really bad with regex how should I edit my current regex code? var word=/@(\w+)/ig;