# How to match foreign wods in BBEdit

Tags: regex, replace, find, pcre, bbedit

I've been researching for a way to do a find and replace for foreign words in BBEdit but I'm having an issue with it.  After research I ran across [Regex - What would be regex for matching foreign characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009993/regex-what-would-be-regex-for-matching-foreign-characters) which led me to Regular-Expressions.info and a text block indicated:

> Matching a single grapheme, whether it's encoded as a single code
>   point, or as multiple code points using combining marks, is easy in
>   Perl, PCRE, PHP, Ruby 2.0, and the Just Great Software applications:
>   simply use \X.

and when I have a word (yes this is made up for testing) `ōallaōallaēēalla` I cannot use `[A-Za-z]*` for the entire word instead it works in segments and the only solution I've been able to come up with is something like `([A-Za-z]*\X{1,10})`.  Is there an alternative approach that wouldn't be too greedy and would pull the entire word instead of pulling it in segments?

Comment: Are you referring to PCRE or to an actual Perl program?

Comment: BBEdit uses perl regex in it's find and replace.

Comment: That would be PCRE. I'll edit your tags.

Comment: What Iis the expected output for `ōallaōallaēēalla`?

Comment: to pull the entire word without breaking it up into segments.

Comment: Doesn't this work for you `\p{L}+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the word boundary `\b` to match everything between to boundaries. That might not get everything, but for your contrived example it works.

```
/\b(.+)\b/
```

If you also want words at the beginning of a line, you need to include those.

```
/(?:\b|^)(.+)\b/
```

[Try it at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gQ7aG8/1). I cannot test if this works in your BBEdit though.