# Capitalizing First Letter for each word in string. Localization issue

Tags: javascript

I am using this function to capitalize first letter of words in the string

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) { 
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); 
  });
}
```

It works well for english words but when I try to type my word with non-English first letter, it makes first two letter to uppercase

> Input string : "şanlıurfa" 
> Output string : "ŞAnlıurfa"

I just want  to capitalize the first letter.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - What would be regex for matching foreign characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009993/regex-what-would-be-regex-for-matching-foreign-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is what is causing the problem, it isn't selecting the first character if it is a special character, change it to `\S+` and it will work as you need. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sft8fkhy/2/) with it working