# Unicode RegEx Not Matching Foreign Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

All I want to do is allow `A-Za-z0-9`, including foreign alphabetic characters like `ñ`, `í`, `ö`, etc. I read that it is indeed possible to do this with the Unicode flag. Hence my expression:

```
re = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/u
```

However, it won't match any of the foreign characters above, which are the only ones I've tested. I suspect it won't match any foreign character at all.

Is there any way to include all or most foreign characters?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010005
Foreign characters are actually two Unicode characters.

Comment: @Skylar beautiful. i believe that works. if you want to make a post containing the info it points to ill select it as the answer!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that, maybe

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]|[^\x00-\x7F])+$
```

or a derivative of that might work, if you'd like to have browser compatibility.

Otherwise,

```
^[\p{L}]+$
```

might simply work.

#### Source

[Unicode Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: Emma's right: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_property_escapes

Comment: aww thats rough. luckily im making an electron application, so i only need to worry about chromium and it works there :D great to know nonetheless!!

Answer (score 2):

For letters, \p{L} will match any Unicode character in the category "letter". Note that this is [not well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_property_escapes).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010005

See also: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html